# How to link dragonvale park to Facebook after already saying no

Tags: dragonvale, facebook

I've already logged in before and when it asked if I wanted to link my park I said no. Now, when I log out and log back in, I log in automatically and it doesn't ask me if I want to link my park. Is there any way to get it to ask me again so I can link my park?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [FAQ section from the developers](http://www.backflipstudios.com/help/androidfaq/), to link Facebook to your park:

> 1. Launch DragonVale
> 2. After DragonVale has loaded, tap on Options at the
>      bottom of the screen
> 3. In the Options menu, tap on Login with the
>      Facebook icon at the bottom. You will be directed to log into Facebook
> 4. You will receive a prompt asking if you want to continue playing your
>      Local park or Facebook, select Facebook. Your Local park should now be
>      associated with your Facebook account
> 5. If you receive an additional prompt after selecting Facebook, you likely will want to pick the
>      higher level park (this will only happen if you have played DragonVale
>      with your Facebook account in the past)

It also notes that this is a permanent process and cannot be undone.